# Plotting the radiation pattern of a dipole antenna using MATLAB

Tags: antenna, matlab, radiation

I want to plot the radiation pattern of a half wavelength dipole antenna using MATLAB. But in dB scale, the plot has undesired peaks.

The code is shown below:

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1e3);
wg =1;
k = 2*pi/wg;
l = wg/2;

U = ((cos(k*l/2*cos(theta))-cos(k*l/2))./(sin(theta))).^2;
Umax = max(U);
Un = U/Umax;

dbUn = 10*log(abs(Un));

polar(theta,dbUn)
grid minor
```

The plot is shown below:

[image: Radiation pattern of half wavelength dipole]

Actually this is a pretty simple algorithm to implement but I do not know what I did wrong.

Comment: Obviously, division by \$\sin(\theta)\$ is going to create a "peak" whenever \$\sin(\theta)=0\$. The question is, why did you do that?

Comment: Because, radiation pattern of the arbitrary length dipole is like that

Comment: It is on Balanis, Antenna Theory, 4th edition, page 172 @AJN

Comment: Well, I'm not going to buy a $150 book just to check your reference, but it seems to me that you have misinterpreted the equation when you coded it for Matlab. Can you show us the original equation, with context?

Comment: @DaveTweed An equation for electric field can be found on http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/dipole.php

Comment: @AldrichTaylor I think simplifed expressions are available for half wave dipoles. http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/halfwave.php

Comment: @AldrichTaylor when you convert to dB, there are negative numbers in dbUn. Polar plots are probably not suitable for such inputs. s the output you got may be the correct one.